# Comparing Last Execution Time to Sheet Entries - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I compare entries in a sheet for a script to run on based on the last execution time of a script? So if the last execution time was 11/22/21 at 12PM, the script would only run on data entries after that point and disregard older entries. Is last execution time a built-in variable?

Comment: No, but you can store the last execution time in `PropertiesService`

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `So if the last execution time was 11/22/21 at 12PM, the script would only run on data entries after that point and disregard older entries.`. In this case, when you can retrieve the last execution time, how do you confirm the data entries after that point and disregard older entries?

Comment: I think you can get the last execution time from Apps Script API listScriptProcesses but I'm not sure how up to date it is.

Comment: Hi there @Riceman! How do you currently save the entries timestamp? Is it inside the Sheet? Or is it on the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)?